# How to update element when data-* attribute changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reflow

I have an element with following css style:
    `#element:after { content: attr(data-percent); }`

I'm trying to change data-percent attribute with JQuery like this
`$('#element').data('percent', '50%');`

Attribute changes, I can check it by `console.log($('#element').data('percent'));`, but it won't redraw and still contains old attribute.

What function should I call to make this element updated?

Comment: I think you want to change the actual attribute: `$('#element').attr('data-percent', '50%');`. `data()` happens to pull in `data-*` attributes, but is different than handling attribute values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's `data` takes the attribute [as the initial value](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5), but it doesn't use it to actually store the data, which is cached in memory instead.

This allows to store whatever value you want, instead of mere strings as per HTML5 standards.

If you actually want to use the attribute to store the data, use

```
$('#element').attr('data-percent', '50%');
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery cannot reference and/or end :after or :before pseudo elements. CSS elements do not appear to automatically update what the referenced attr() changes.

My suggestion would be to not use a pseudo element.

Comment: CSS Pseudo elements *do* reflect the content of the attribute they reference. As a matter of fact, it's one of the most evident (and useful) behaviors they have. It works in IE8+, which is quite a plus.

Comment: Oh? Could you provide an example? I'm curious.

Comment: Sure: http://jsbin.com/powed/1 (add /edit at the end if you want to see the source). The second change, using `dataset`, doesn't work in IE.